Laravel pest api testing always returns 404 error
I recently upgraded my laravel version from 10 to 11. I followed the steps to installed the pest for the api testing. But everytime when i run the test, it always throws the 404 error only.
phpunit.xml
<phpunit bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php">
    <php>
        <env name="APP_URL" value="http://localhost/project/api/public/api" />
    </php>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>

tests/Feature/ExampleTest.php
<?php

it('can access the login page', function () {
    $response = $this->get('/login');

    $response->assertStatus(200);
});

Result:
   FAILED  Tests\Feature\ExampleTest > it can access the login page                                                                                                                           
  Expected response status code [200] but received 404.
Failed asserting that 404 is identical to 200.

  at tests/Feature/ExampleTest.php:6
      2▕ 
      3▕ it('can access the login page', function () {
      4▕     $response = $this->get('/login');
      5▕ 
  ➜   6▕     $response->assertStatus(200);
      7▕ });
      8▕ 

routes/api.php
Route::group([
    'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1',
], function () {
    Route::get('/login', function () {
        return 'test';
    });
});


Shouldn't it be /api/login

I already added the api in phpunit.xml <env name="APP_URL" value="http://localhost/project/api/public/api" />
